# Since we cannot do i++, how to code looks neater

Tags: scala, int

I need to find the first `'\t'` symbol in an array. Since we do not have `i++` or so in scala I ended up writing the following:

```
val data: Array[Byte] = //..
var i = 0
while(i < data.length && data{val j = i; i += 1; j} != '\t'){ }
```

Can we refactor it in a neater way?

Comment: Are you asking how to construct a while loop?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Exactly. I did but it looks like a workaround the `++` opeartor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something until a condition is met, you would probably be better off splitting up the while and for loops. Declaring a for loop inside the declaration of a while loop is ugly and probably unpredictable when it gets more complicated.

Also, ***don't use `var`***. It is best practice to keep everything as immutable as possible when using Scala.

Something like this technically does the job:

```
def iterateUntilByte(byte: Byte, array: Array[Byte]): Any = {
  for(i <- array.indices) {
    if(array(i) != byte) /* do something */ else return
  }
}
```

[[ScalaFiddle]](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/z4HYQB2/0)

Or a more condensed version:

```
def iterateUntilByte(byte: Byte, array: Array[Byte]): Any = {
  array.map(a => if(a != byte) /* do something */) // can be foreach if return type is Unit
}
```

[[ScalaFiddle]](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/z4HYQB2/1)

You can modify the above code to do whatever you want when you find `\t`, like `if(a == byte) {...} else {...}` (if you are only interested in the `\t` entry).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `var` (if at all possible within your time constraints; note that this is always possible).

Don't use `return` (ever ever ever! [Read this](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html)).

You should also never write a loop. This seems hard when you first start using Scala coming from an imperative language but there is always a better way. Attempting to write a loop is not the "scala way", not functional programming.

You can use `takeWhile` and `foreach` to do something until some condition is met. You can use `find` to obtain the first item that matches some condition. You can use `indexOf`. You can use `zipWithIndex`. You can use `filter`. You can use `foldLeft`, `collect`, `groupBy`, or of course `map`. You can use convoluted combinations of these. You can use recursion to "return early". You do not ever need to "write a loop".

Your original question seems like an XY problem, but it appears `val i = data.indexOf('\t')` would do it, unless the data does not contain `'\t'`, then it will be `-1`. More ideas;

```
val i = data.indexOf('\t') match {
  case -1 => data.length-1
  case n => n
}

val i = Some(data.indexOf('\t')).filterNot(_ == -1).getOrElse(data.length-1)

def i2(data: Array[Byte]): Array[Byte] = data.takeWhile(_ != '\t')

def printUpToTab(data: Array[Byte]): Unit = i2(data).foreach(println)

// Warning: obtaining the index of something is not usually necessary.
//  Step back and consider a cleaner solution.
def tabIndices(data: Array[Byte]): List[Int] = data.zipWithIndex.collect {
  case ('\t', n) =>
    println(s"Found a tab at $n")
    n
}.toList

// does a list contain less than N tab characters? Simple solution:
def containsLessThanNtabs(data: List[Byte], n: Int): Boolean =
  data.count(_ == '\t') < n

// This version will "return early" when N tabs are found,
//  not counting through the entire list.
// This could be more efficient for very long lists.
// You must have a `List` to use the `::` construct.
def recursiveVersion(data: List[Byte], n: Int): Boolean = {
  def recurse(bytes: List[Byte], count: Int): Boolean = 
    if (count >= n) false
    else {
      bytes match {
        case Nil => true
        case '\t' :: tail => recurse(tail, count+1)
        case _ :: tail => recurse(tail, count)
      }
    }

  recurse(data, 0)
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you want help extending these ideas to your actual problem.